# exclude a class from a used namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

The first statement of all my C# files is "**using System;**".
Now with framework version 4 this namespace contains a class called "Action". This is also the name for a class im my own code in a regularly used namespace. Now there is of course a conflict. Ofcourse I can resolve this conflict by using explicit "MyNamespace.Action" where ever I was using "Action" before. This are several hundreds if not thousands of lines. Or I could not use the System namespace, which of course leads to many other problems. I would like to write something like "using System but not System.Action", but I cannot find a statement to do this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't.

But you can add `using Action = MyNamespace.Action`. This will be highly confusing for new developers, though, as Action is a fundamental part of .net since 3.5 so I strongly suggest you rename your class.

Comment: Learn something new every day. I knew you could alias a namespace, didn't realise you could alias a _type_.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, thank you! Unfortunately I cannot rename my class, because my software is a class library used by many customers for years now. Now when we go to framework 4 they will also have to use this framework and will also have to include this line in every file which uses the namespace of our class.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` directive has two uses:

To permit the use of types in a namespace so you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace:

```
using System.Text;
```

To create an alias for a namespace or a type (*you could go for this one*).

```
using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
```

The `using` keyword can also be used to create `using` statements, which define when an object will be disposed. See `using` statement for more information.

[using directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)